# How to remove glass doorknob

Tags: doorknob

I need to paint my doors, and wanted to clean up by hardware. I can't figure out how to remove the old glass door knobs. I've removed every screw (including the set screws on both sides). I've tried pulling it out. I've tried rotating the outdoor knob, and unscrewing the interior. I can't figure out how to get it apart. Thanks for any help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an old style knob that screws onto it's turning bar, and then is locked into place.

Simply apply some extra force and turn the knob counter clockwise to loosen until it comes off.

Comment: After a zillion years, it's possible you have some corrosion and crud buildup on the square threaded shaft. Squirt some penetrating oil into the set screw holes *before* torquing the knob to destruction.

Comment: Or part of the screw is still in there.  If that's the case you can take a tap and really small drill bit to drill it out. Preserving the knob can cause a lot of time with this type of "road-bump"